# laravel 4 view::share doesn´t work

Tags: php, authentication, view, laravel, share

I would like to share the username through all my views once the user is logged in. I tried this direct in imy routes.php:

```
View::share('user', $user);
```

but it doesn´t share anything. I tried also to put it in the following route:

```
Route::post('auth', function()
{

    $user = Input::get('username');

    View::share('user', $user);

    $credentials = array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
{
    //Cache::put('user', $user);
    return View::make('panel')->with('user', $user);
}
//return 'user :' .$user. ' and pass : ' .$pass;
return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Could you please help me out?

EDIT:

i solved using this in every blade i need it:

```
$user = Auth::user()->username;
```

but i would like to define it once for all my views - can somebody give me a tip?

Comment: Are you placing this user name in different locations on every page if not then just do it once in the main layout. Even if you are couldn't you grab the variable and assign it in your main layout (you are using layouts right?)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a route filter which shares the username to the view. Now you can apply this filter to every route, or route group to use it in your views.

```
Route::filter('shared.user', function()
{
    $user = '';
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        $user = Auth::user()->username;
    }
    View::share('user', $user);
});

Route::get('hello', array('before' => 'shared.user', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}));

Route::group(array('before' => 'shared.user'), function()
{
    // routes which show the username
});
```